# Setting Variable Values During Testing

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

My current situation (although I need this for many other, similar, situations) is that I am writing an app that is querying a DataBase.

Now, while coding / debugging, I'd prefer not to have to keep constantly re-entering my DB credentials. However, if a user runs the executable, I would like them to have to enter their credentials.

I've looked into PreProcessor Directives such as:

```
#If DEBUG Then
    Public Property DB_UserName As String = "MyUserName"
    Public Property DB_Password As String = "MyPassword"
#Else
    Public Property DB_UserName As String = ""
    Public Property DB_Password As String = ""
#End If
```

But that relies on me having to change my project's configuration before releasing it into the wild. (And yes, I know it's not good programming practice to leave things such as credentials in my code, but please ignore that part for now - Like I said, this is just an example.)

What I'm looking for / wondering if it exists is a way to be able to set variables / write code that will be processed while I'm coding / in the Visual Studio environment, but won't be processed if the executable is being run without having to change any project properties.

Does such a thing exist? How would I implement it?

Thanks!

Comment: What about just storing the values in a config file, and then just don't ship that file or settings to the customers?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use the PreProcessor Directives? It makes the most sense to have it in Debug mode when doing testing and then change it to Release when you are going to compile the executable. This way you can even have different `.config` files to changes settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to hard-code the values, you can check to see if you are running in the development environment with a method like this:

```
Private Function processStartedByVisualStudioDebugger() As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean = False
    Try
        If AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainManager.ToString().IndexOf("vshost", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 Then
            result = True
        End If
    Catch
    End Try
    Return result
End Function
```

However, I think simply storing the values in a configuration file makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks @Steven - Answers the question AND gives me the generally preferred solution. As always, you're awesome!!!

Comment: ... I know it might be bad practice, but I **LOVE** your solution, @Steven - Did EXACTLY what I wanted! - Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Settings](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/72654-using-settings/).

I think it would be better than storing directly in code.
Just release your executable with a different settings file or even without it.

Comment: Thanks, @Jamby - Gonna look into that more. Steven's solution gave me exactly what I was looking for, though.